# Locate a char inside a tridimensional array of strings

Tags: c++, string, search, matrix, char

I have a tri dimensional array of strings and I want to make a function to count how many strings in the matrix have the char c in the position k. I made this function:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

typedef vector <string> Row;
typedef vector <Row> Matrix;

int numer_of_words (const Matrix& m, char c, int k) {
    int sum = 0;
    int rows = m.size();
    for (int i=0; i < rows; ++i) {
        int words = m[i].size();
        for (int j=0; j < words; ++j) {
            string s = m[i][j];
            if (s.length() <= k) {
                if (s[k] == c) ++sum;
            }
        }

    }
    return sum;
}
```

in other words sum should be increased when s[k] = c (if s[k] exists). I dont get a compilation error but the code doesn't work.

Comment: I think he's got a bunch of typos from converting the code to english for SO, it's likely the code runs on his machine.

Comment: yeah it's a typo sorry, i had to translate it from another language

Comment: ok I just editted it and I think there are no typos anymore

Comment: @soon i changed that and I got this error "your program is too slow, or perhaps it would never stop. The most common reasons for the latter case are trying to access an invalid memory reference, using too much memory (the recursive stack included), floating point exceptions, and printing too much output."

Comment: @Buradi: Wow... Who said that?

Comment: Also, you should avoid copying in the line `string s = m[i][j];`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (s.length() <= k) {
    if (s[k] == c) ++sum;
}
```

Here you access `s[k]` only if `s`'s length is **less than** or equal to k, which is the opposite of what you want. The condition should be `s.length() > k`.

Comment: same thing even if I delete the first condition i get the same error